# NVIDIA GeForce GT 640 compatible with 12.10?

Tags: nvidia, 12.10, ati, graphics

I was wondering if the MSI NVIDIA GeForce GT 640 1GB card is compatible with ubuntu quantal quetzal. If it is not, suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Should be - see [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12025809&postcount=2).

Considering one myself since this card is available in [silently-cooled versions from ASUS](http://www.asus.com/Graphics_Cards/GT640DCSL2GD3/#overview).  Research indicates it's probably the most powerful silently-cooled NVIDIA card available.

Currently I'm using a GT 520 with 304.43 drivers.  No issues.  So I'll be going NVIDIA again.

Edit: I installed the card and everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a GT 630 with 2GB of DDR3 now with the 310.19 version driver from Nvidia. I run dual screens and all seems to work well. I would imagine you would be OK with GT 640

I must admit, I'm not sure how much of the card's capabilities are being used...I mostly run a bunch of VMware instances.

I have recently disabled 3D accleration on the VMs because I started getting a compatability warning when I started a VM and my displays are sometimes...sticky. I tested glx gears at full screen on one of my screens an got a crummy 70 fps!!! Ouch...

Maybe we could help each other figure this out? I can help you through the install process if you'd like...it was kind of a pain.

Cheers!